# How do I disable use of the space bar and enter keys on my webpage?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, key

I'm making a site where a user repeatedly clicks a button to increase his/her score. Apart from using clicking bots, people can also click the button, and then without letting go of the mouse, hold down the enter or space bar key to get clicks at ridiculous speed, and can just place an object on one of these keys to hold it down all night etc.

Is there any way to stop this?

I tried adding a javascript script that disables the enter key, but it didn't work. Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Maybe have a look at [jKey](http://oscargodson.com/labs/jkey/). It is a jQuery plugin to allow key shortcuts, but you will maybe be able to do what you want with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can measure the time between successive clicks and if it less than say 100ms ignore the click.

Comment: Won't that still mean if the key is left pressed down the user would get the maximum possible score allowed by the system? Or are you suggesting that each ignored click resets the timer?

Comment: It does. But you can couple this with an extra piece of code which says "if the user's clicking rate has been over 4 per second for the past 10 seconds, then something is wrong" . Not many people can sustain that clicking rate for a long time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had actually thought about doing that before but then I dismissed it because I didn't think it was possible. How would I go about doing this?
Thanks

Comment: How would you set the timer ? I think some people can manage 10 clicks a second.

Comment: @Taimur - I think you should post a new question for the time. I can't answer that one :)
@Krtek - Even if they can manage it, they can't sustain it for a long period of time. And even if they could, I wouldn't build a website asking visitors to break their fingers to get points.

Answer (score 1):

could you not set a flag when the button is clicked, then start a timer?  When the timer expires unset the flag again.

When the button is clicked check if the flag is set, if it is do not increase the score.  you could also reset the timer to stop people just increasing their score as soon as the timer goes off.

My jQuery is not all that so I can't give an example off the top of my head.

This would have the advantage that it should work against bots as well, although the bot could just be programmed to click as soon as the flag expired...

Comment: that sounds like a good plan, thanks
could you point me in the right direction as to how I would go about doing it?
thanks